# How to make an uneven bandsaw worktable even?

Tags: band-saw

The worktable on my bandsaw is not flat. It's die cast aluminum. I should have returned it when it was still under warranty, but I didn't use it a lot and didn't really realize there was a problem until now that I'm trying to make some more precise cuts.

I think the problem is the angle support (circled in the picture). I thought about trying to bend the table into place but then realized it would just go back to the shape of angle support. Although, as I'm writing this, I wonder if I could add a washer to push the left side into better alignment. Guess I'll try it out and report back.

To be clear, the left side is flat and the right side is flat. The problem is that whichever side I align with the blade, the other half will tilt down toward the side by a degree or so. So this makes it difficult to push a piece of wood down the center with it wanting to wobble.

[image]

Comment: Most low-end Porter Cable tools aren't great. I've found them to be consistently "good enough" but not much more. You might have a 50/50 chance of getting a flat table with another try. (Is or Isn't) but you could build a table for it relatively easily,

Comment: Without more information this question is too broad and invites opinion-based responses, so I am closing it.  You can post a related question with more information on the model, what you mean by uneven, and perhaps, some pictures to clarify what the problem is in more detail.  The [tour] may help clarify the problem with the question as posted here.

Comment: You could even just [edit] this question to include more info. How "not flat" is it? If it's just slightly off, it might be worth just sanding down. What's the table made of? If it's cast iron, I'd expect it to be pretty darn flat and would contact PC about a warranty replacement. If it's stamped sheet metal, well... you get what you pay for. I've seen more than a few people who have made their own `tool` tables (band saw, drill press, etc.) - you might consider that as an option.

Comment: Thanks @Ashlar, I will make another post that's more specific.

Comment: @Ashlar actually I've just edited this one. I can put it in a new question if that would be preferable though.

Comment: @gnicko if you have any resources I could look to on how to build your own table please share. Thanks!

Comment: @BVernon Question reopened.

Comment: Always best to just edit the existing question to bring it in line, unless it's just a total mess. You've done well!

Comment: There's a [YouTuber named Mattias Wendel](https://www.youtube.com/@matthiaswandel) who has built a large number of tools (including 3 _very_ large band saws) out of wood. You can watch a few of his videos on the band saw builds to see how he does the tables. Of course, you'd have to modify yours to fit the existing mounting/tilt mechanism, but it'd give you an idea of what's involved in building your own. I'll note that he's an incredible cheapskate, but also an incredible and talented engineer. He's made some amazing things out of found junk. (Just a fan, not affiliated in any way.)

Comment: Since this is just aluminium have you considered lapping it until the top is co-planar? This would be a messy job and if you don't currently have any really good abrasives it might take more time than you'd like but it's totally doable (hint: best abrasive out there probably Cubitron II). And of course 2nd option is simply to make a thin top that will cap this one; make it flat then simply shimming it should be more than sufficient for the downward loads experienced by the typical bandsaw in use. Maybe it's so close to flat that just a sheet of good 3/4" ply laid over will do enough by itself.

Comment: Could take it to a machine shop to have them flatten it. A good machine shop can flatten an engine block head to within 0.0001" or so, getting an aluminum table to 0.01" should be a walk in the park!

Comment: @Graphus You just reminded me that laying a sheet of plywood over it was actually my first thought but I abandoned it because I only have about 3.5" of height (just slightly more). I may yet end up doing this though and accepting the fact that I just need to buy a more expensive band saw when I'm able.

Comment: @FreeMan Great thought... I think the problem here is actually probably not the table itself though after further investigation. I think the angle support is pulling it out of alignment. I want to try putting some washers in and see if this helped but haven't gotten to it yet... we'll see this weekend.

Comment: Yeah vertical space is at a premium on many a bandsaw, even many a rung or two above this one! Tweaking the tilting support is certainly worth a shot, seems like there's nothing to lose trying a fix there.

Comment: Have you considered that the curved support you've highlighted might be bent and that a replacement part might fix all your problems? I'm not sure, hence a comment, not an answer, just a thought that occurred to me.

Comment: @FreeMan Good point. Actually I did have a thought that it might have been machined/manufactured poorly.